# Is this ternary conditional ?: correct (Objective) C syntax?

Tags: objective-c, c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I didn't think this was possible but apparently in Objective C it is allowed:

```
int a = b ?: c;
```

So you see what they're doing here, they're leaving out the second part of the ternary expression, such that if b is nonzero, b is used as the second part.

It's clever but as far as I know this is against K&R C, and probably ANSI C.

If not, I've been missing out of a terribly clever syntax trick for years...alas!

Update:
It is gcc.

Comment: Which compiler? GCC has this as an extension, albeit a deprecated one.

Comment: More correct term is conditional. Ternary just means it's an operator that takes 3 arguments.

Answer (score 83):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A

> A GNU extension to C allows omitting the second operand, and using implicitly the first operand as the second also:
>
> ```
> a = x ? : y;
> ```
>
> The expression is equivalent to
>
> ```
> a = x ? x : y;
> ```
>
> except that if x is an expression, it is evaluated only once. The difference is significant if evaluating the expression has side effects.

Answer (score 9):

This behaviour is defined for both `gcc` and `clang`. If you're building macOS or iOS code, there's no reason **not** to use it.

I would not use it in portable code, though, without carefully considering it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [GNU C extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals). Check you compiler settings (look for C flavor). Not sure if it's part of Clang, the only information I could get is in [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html):

> #### Introduction
>
> This document describes the language extensions provided by Clang. In addition to the language extensions listed here, Clang aims to support a broad range of GCC extensions. Please see the GCC manual for more information on these extensions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat > foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int b = 2;
  int c = 4;
  int a = b ?: c;
  printf("a: %d\n", a);
  return 0;
}
$ gcc -pedantic -Wall foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:7: warning: ISO C forbids omitting the middle term of a ?: expression
```

So no, it's not allowed. What gcc emits in this case does this:

```
$ ./a.out 
a: 2
```

So the undefined behaviour is doing what you say in your question, even though you don't want to rely on that.

Comment: I don't love your use of the word "undefined" here. It would be better to call it nonstandard; the behaviour *IS* defined for GCC, just not for ISO C. That makes it undefined for other compilers and not portable, but it's still defined for GCC.

Comment: @steven As the question was whether it's correct C syntax, then the fact that it's undefined behaviour in C is the correct answer regardless of what your compiler does.