# How can I simplify this code (conversion to NSDictionary)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, applozic

I want to convert response to `NSDictionary`. Response is an implementation of `ALRegistrationResponse` (https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Chat-iOS-Framework/blob/master/Applozic/DomainClasses/ALRegistrationResponse.m).

```
NSDictionary *_response = @
{
    @"message":[response message] != nil ? [response message] : [NSNull null],
    @"deviceKey":[response deviceKey] != nil ? [response deviceKey] : [NSNull null],
    @"userKey":[response userKey] != nil ? [response userKey] : [NSNull null],
    @"contactNumber":[response contactNumber] != nil ? [response contactNumber] : [NSNull null],
    @"lastSyncTime":[response lastSyncTime] != nil ? [response lastSyncTime] : [NSNull null],
    @"currentTimeStamp":[response currentTimeStamp] != nil ? [response currentTimeStamp] : [NSNull null],
    @"brokerURL":[response brokerURL] != nil ? [response brokerURL] : [NSNull null],
    @"imageLink":[response imageLink] != nil ? [response imageLink] : [NSNull null],
    @"statusMessage":[response statusMessage] != nil ? [response statusMessage] : [NSNull null],
    @"encryptionKey":[response encryptionKey] != nil ? [response encryptionKey] : [NSNull null],
    @"displayName":[response displayName] != nil ? [response displayName] : [NSNull null],
    @"notificationSoundFileName":[response notificationSoundFileName] != nil ? [response notificationSoundFileName] : [NSNull null]
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760561/is-this-ternary-conditional-correct-objective-c-syntax + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177719/testing-for-nil-in-objective-c-ifx-nil-vs-ifx ?

Comment: Thanks for links! How about iteration over all the fields?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but `NSArray *keys = @[@"message", @"deviceKey", etc.]; NSMutableDictionary *_response = [NSMutableDictionary  new]; for (NSString *aKey in keys){[_response setObject:[response valueForKeyPath:key]?:[NSNull null] forKey:key];}`

Comment: Its superclass has a -dictionary() function. It might do what you wanted. I realize this is a bit late.
NSCoding, isn't on it, but can/should for storing

Answer (score 1):

At least a bit cleaner is the following syntax:

```
NSDictionary *_response = @{
    @"message": [response message] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"deviceKey": [response deviceKey] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"userKey": [response userKey] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"contactNumber": [response contactNumber] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"lastSyncTime": [response lastSyncTime] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"currentTimeStamp": [response currentTimeStamp] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"brokerURL": [response brokerURL] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"imageLink": [response imageLink] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"statusMessage": [response statusMessage] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"encryptionKey": [response encryptionKey] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"displayName": [response displayName] ?: [NSNull null],
    @"notificationSoundFileName": [response notificationSoundFileName] ?: [NSNull null]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use the keys as selectors:

```
NSArray *keys = @[@"message", @"deviceKey", @"userKey", @"contactNumber", @"lastSyncTime", @"currentTimeStamp", @"brokerURL", @"imageLink", @"statusMessage", @"encryptionKey", @"displayName", @"notificationSoundFileName"];
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(key);
    [dict setObject:[response performSelector: selector] ?: [NSNull null] forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a function to check for nil?
Something like this:

```
NSDictionary *_response = @
{
    @"message":checkForNil([response message])
],...
```